# Can pdftk merge annotations from multiple files (same document)?

Tags: pdf, pdftk, annotations

I have multiple versions of the same document, with different annotations (comments, highlights, etc.). For example, suppose I sent a PDF document to some colleagues and they sent it back with the annotations.

Adobe Acrobat has an option for importing annotations from multiple files into the same document.

Can I do something similar with pdftk?